# Программное создание кастомных ячеек

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Здравствуйте. У меня такой вопрос ,как можно программно создать кастомные ячейки для tableview. Чтобы они были не как по умолчанию в одну строку одна ячейка, а чтоб  ячейки были квадратные,то есть и по столбцам и по строкам их было несколько?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте новый класс UITableViewCell, в котором определите свойства для каждого столбца в ячейке. Например у нас два столбца с картинкой и кнопкой:

CustomCell.h

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *firstImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *firstButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *secondImage;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *secondButton;

@end
```

CustomCell.m

```
@implementation CustomCell

@synthesize firstImage;
@synthesize secondImage;
@synthesize firstButton;
@synthesize secondButton;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        //Инициализируем наши firstImage, firstButton, secondImage, secondButton и добавляем на сцену

    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Соответственно, в инициализации вы можете задать нужный размер и положение каждого элемента, к кнопкам добавить селектор для вызова определенной функции.

Answer (score 1):

Может вам нужено UICollectionView и UICollectionViewCell?

Comment: я пока постигаю так сказать азы. делаю на xcode 4.2 под ios 5. а там вроде нет UICollectionView

Comment: может пора обновиться до xcode 5 и постигать разработку уже под ios7. Устройств не так много с ios5 осталось.

Comment: Вот интересная статистика http://david-smith.org/iosversionstats/

Answer (score 1):

вам нужно использовать UICollectionView, вот подробный  [мануал](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf) от разработчиков apple с картинками и пояснениями

Comment: Алексей, я же уже написал про UICollectionView -)

Comment: @huffman а у меня есть хорошая ссылка :P